# Explicit map from $\mathbb{N}^t \to \mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

I know how to proof the following map from $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is injective :

$(n_1, n_2) \to  \binom{n_{1}+n_{2}} 2 + n_{1}$.

An obvious generalization of the above map from $\mathbb{N^t} \to  \mathbb{N} $ seem like as follows:

$(n_1, \dots, n_t) \to \sum_{j = 1}^t \binom{\sum_{i = 1}^j n_i} j$.

I have a feeling that this generalized map from $\mathbb{N^t} \to  \mathbb{N} $ is also injective. But I don't know how to prove it. Geometrically it seems very difficult as compared to the proof for the case $t=2$. I think there should be some algebraic proof. A rough sketch of the proof or any suitable reference book where I can read proof for this general case will be a great help.

Comment: @TonyK, I did not get you, why should $(n,n,n)$ map to $n^3$?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't follow. But there is another problem: Does your $\Bbb N$ start from $0$ or $1$? If $0$, then $(0,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ both map to $0$ (where we take $\binom{n}{r}=0$ if $r>n$). If $1$, then your expression is always $\ge t$, so it is not a bijection. So I think at least you need to subtract $t-1$ from the result.

Comment: @TonyK, set $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3, \cdot \cdot \cdot \}$

Comment: But even if you subtract $t-1$ from the result, there is no triple $(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ that maps to $2$, or $3$, or $5$. So it looks like your idea needs modifying.

Comment: @TonyK, Okay surjectivity has an issue but does the map injective. I want to prove its injectivity

Comment: That completely changes your question! Injectivity is easy, just use Gödel numbering: $(n_1,n_2,n_3)\to 2^{n_1}\cdot 3^{n_2}\cdot 5^{n_3}$ etc.

Comment: @TonyK, no I want the same map to prove as an injective map. I already know this map you have given.

Comment: Your original question is busted, so I'm done here.

Comment: If all you have is a "feeling" that your map is injective, or maybe even bijective, then you should not be thinking about how to prove it; you should be thinking about how to *test* it. You should be calculating the image of lots of triples of small numbers to see what kind of coverage it gives. Only after you've done enough calculation to have some serious reason to believe it's true should you start to think about proving it (and of course if your calculations show it's false, then you're done).

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thanks a lot, I did it and found that my assertion that the map is bijective is incorrect. Even for the case, $t=2$ as $1$ will have no preimage. But it still seems to be an injective map that I have no idea how to prove.

Comment: Just a small correction: you didn't "find out" that your map isn't bijective; I told you it wasn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is connected to something called [Combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system) (also combinadics), which states that for a fixed integer $t>0$, every integer $k\geq 0$ can be uniquely(!) represented as
$$
k=\binom{c_1}{1}+\binom{c_2}{2}+\dots+\binom{c_t}{t}
$$
where $c_t>\dots>c_2>c_1\geq 0$ are integers. If we let $c_j=\sum_{i = 1}^j n_i$ in your problem, the condition above is satisfied, so we can use the uniqueness of combinadics representation of above to show injectivity. To see it better let's denote
$$
f(n_1,n_2,\dots,n_t)=\binom{n_1}{1}+\binom{n_1+n_2}{2}+\dots+\binom{n_1+n_2+\dots+n_t}{t},
$$
and assume $f(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_t)=f(b_1,b_2,\dots,b_t)$ for some positive integers $a_i,b_i$. Then letting $c_j=\sum_{i = 1}^j a_i$ and $d_j=\sum_{i = 1}^j b_i$, and so $\binom{c_1}{1}+\binom{c_2}{2}+\dots+\binom{c_t}{t}=\binom{d_1}{1}+\binom{d_2}{2}+\dots+\binom{d_t}{t}$. By the uniqueness of combinadics representation, it follows $c_j=d_j$ for all $j$, which implies $a_i=b_i$ subsequently, and injectivity follows.

However $f$ will not be surjective because $n_i$ are positive and so $c_1 = n_1 \neq 0$, thus we miss values whose representation would have $c_1=0$ in the combinadics representation. Since you map to positive integers, you are allowed to ommit $0$, but that is the only one value you don't need to map to... For example, for any $t>1$, the integer $\binom{0}{1}+\binom{2}{2}+\dots +\binom{t}{t}=0+1+\dots +1=t-1$ will not be represented by your map.

So for completeness, check a proof of uniqueness of combinadics system, see for example [Numbers Expressed as Sums of Binomial Coefficients](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Numbers_Expressed_as_Sums_of_Binomial_Coefficients), or [Proof of bijection for combinatorial number system](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.05794.pdf) (you can find many more by yourself now).

By the way, you can use the above to turn the combinadics into an explicit bijection $g:\mathbb{N^t} \to  \mathbb{N}$ (where $\mathbb{N}$ excludes $0$). The condition $c_t>\dots>c_2>c_1\geq 0$ corresponds to sums of $n_i$'s with $n_1\geq 0$ and $n_j >0$ for $j>1$. So, shifting $n_1$ and resulting value by $1$, we can see
$$
g(n_1,n_2,\dots,n_t)=\binom{n_1-1}{1}+\binom{n_1+n_2-1}{2}+\dots+\binom{n_1+\dots+n_t-1}{t}+1
$$
is such bijection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and moreover giving a bijective map, that I am so excited about, from $\mathbb{N^t} \to \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 1):

You can construct an injective map $\Bbb{N}^t \to \Bbb{N}$ via the map $(n_1, ..., n_t) \to p_1^{n_1} ... p_t^{n_t}$, where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number. In fact, by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, this extends to a bijection of $$S := \bigcup_{t \geq 1} \Bbb{N}^t \leftrightarrow \{2, 3, 4, 5, ...\}.$$