How exactly is pascal's identity being used between steps here?
This should be simple but I just don't see it.
Prove that every integer $n \geq 0$ can be written as
$
n = \binom{c_1}{1} + \binom{c_2}{2} + \binom{c_3}{3}
$
for some integers $0 \leq c_1 < c_2 < c_3.$
We will prove this by induction on n
When $n = 0$, we have
$0 = \binom{0}{1} + \binom{1}{2} + \binom{2}{3}$
Suppose that we have found integers $0 \leq c_1 < c_2 < c_3$ such that
$n = \binom{c_1}{1} + \binom{c_2}{2} + \binom{c_3}{3}.$
Now, consider (n+1):
$n+1 = \binom{c_1+1}{1} + \binom{c_2}{2} + \binom{c_3}{3}$
If $c_1 + 1 < c_2$, then we are done. Otherwise, $c_1 + 1 = c_2$, and so by Pascal’s identity, we have
$n+1 = \binom{0}{1} + \binom{c_2+1}{2} + \binom{c_3}{3}$

This is a special case of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4173799/42969.

If $c_1+1=c_2$ then $\binom{c_1+1}1 + \binom{c_2}2 = \binom{c_2}1 + \binom{c_2}2 = \binom{c_2+1}2$. [And $\binom01=0$ so it can be inserted on the right-hand side.]
